# Sqflite flutter communicating with main isolate

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite, dart-isolates, flutter-workmanager

A number of plugins (flutter_uploader, workmanager etc) call a top level static handler in dart using PluginUtilities.getCallbackHandle which runs from a separate isolate.

In this handler we want to access sqflite. We understand we cannot do this from a background isolate and need to use a send/receive port to send a message to main isolate to perform the sqflite operation.

However, it seems like there is no good documentation on how to access the main isolate when we did not create the isolate we are currently in.

Is this possible?